# Variable watch in PHP

Tags: php, watch

Does PHP have the ability to watch a variable (or object property) and run a function when its value changes, similar to [Gecko's Javascript `watch` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Watch)?

Comment: Do you want to detail what the ultimate goal is? E.g. just being able to watch a var, or something else which you need the watch for?

Answer (score 1):

[XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) *might* have this, but I don't know for sure.

If you're trying to debug a member variable on an object, you can use overloading:

```
public function __set($var, $val)
{
    if ($var == 'interesting') {
        echo "$var set to: ";
        var_dump($val);
    }
    $this->$var = $val;
}
```

Comment: According to PHP docs (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) : "__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible members."  It doesn't filter all member accesses.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible when using XDebug along side an IDE like eclipse.