# Monitor a PHP variable for change in value

Tags: php

I am actually trying to monitor a PHP variable (may be as a separate thread but not possible in PHP) and fire a PHP function whenever the value of the variable changes.

eg: lets take a variable $_GLOBALS['foo']=1;

if at any point in the code, the value of $_GLOBALS['foo'] changes to something else, i want to fire a PHP function immediately.

The variable can be anywhere inside a loop or in a function,etc.

**Why i want this**: I have a variable which stores the last error occured as a text. If the value of the variable changes from "" to something else, i want to trigger an error. My LOGIC may seem a bit strange but this is what i would like to do.

Thanx in advance.

**Edit:** I tried: [How to use monitors in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682120/how-to-use-monitors-in-php) and [How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications) but does not seem to solve the problem.

**The Code (Thought this could solve some of your doubts on my question):**

```
public function addtag($tagarray,$uid,$tagtype="1")
{
    $dbobj=new dboperations();
    $uiobj=new uifriend();
    $tagid=$uiobj->randomstring(30,DB_SOCIAL,SOCIAL_TAG,tag_tagid);
    $c=0;
    foreach($tagarray as $tags)
    {
        $c++;
        $tagname=$tags["tagname"];
        $taguid=$tags["tagid"];
        $dbobj->dbinsert("INSERT INTO ".SOCIAL_TAG." (".tag_tagid.",".tag_fuid.",".tag_tuid.",".tag_tagname.",".tag_tagtype.") VALUES
                ('$tagid','$uid','$taguid','$tagname','$tagtype')",DB_SOCIAL);
    }
    if($c==0)
    {
        $lasterror="No tags were added";return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return $tagid;
    }
}
```

Here, if i call a error handling function instead of monitoring the variable, it wont be advisable in my case since the error handling function may do any operation like give alert and redirect to a page or any similar operation.

I asked this question cause, i thought what if the script does not reach the line 
return ""; 
It would affect the project's workflow. Thats what i am worried about.

And the variable i was talking about is $lasterror and i have many functions like this where $lasterror is used.

Comment: A quick Google search brought this up, not sure if it's any good for you, but have a read through - http://www.alexatnet.com/articles/programming-events-php

Comment: This seems similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385420/variable-watch-in-php but they did not get an answer.

Comment: @francisco.preller Thanx for the quick reply. I went through it but in that case, we have to trigger the events manually, its not automatic.

Comment: I guess my biggest question is When exactly do you want to check this? Would it be unreasonable to check the $lasterror on page load? Or if the error is generated on page creation, check it as a last stop before sending the view.

Comment: @vignesh what do you mean by 'automatic'? This isn't going to happen unless you program the behaviour in. What you are describing is a need for an event system.

Comment: @DavidHoude: i would like to check this whenever a change in variable value occurs, it can be at any time.

Comment: @vascowhite: yes and sorry for the phrase "automatic". what i would want to know is how to program this behavior in so that a function fires when the variable value changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in PHP, and there's no easy way to add it. It doesn't really feel right for the way the language works anyway.

Instead of setting a variable, you could build a custom function that handles the error - or use PHP's built-in error handling functionality using a [custom error handler.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Another error handling method which comes close to what you want to do (I think) is [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: Agreed - the best way would to use proper OOP and then log changes/accesses to the variable.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. I could do it but i think it might affect the project's workflow. If it does not, then this is not an issue.

Comment: @Pekka: I think you are right. I better change my workflow to use exceptions because there is no other way to do this in PHP since i researched a bit more now. Thanx a lot..

Answer (score 6):

I saw this, so I built this:

https://github.com/leedavis81/vent

Should solve your problem.